# Strange result using factory of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

```
.factory("CountingService", function() {
  var i = 0;
    this.getNumber = (function() {
      return i += i + 1;

    })();

    return this;
  })
```

I have this service to update my cart number, but it seems doesn't get the latest localstorage data. because I tested it on my controllers like this

`console.log(CountingService.getNumber )` or even

```
$timeout(function(){

    console.log(CountingService.getNumber )

},1000);
```

I've debugging this for hours.

Comment: And what is `getItem`?

Comment: You should to understand, that your factory initialization code will executed once. So, `getNumber` will represent the value at factory initialization time. You should to export function to have ability to get fresh data.

Comment: @vp_arth how to do that?

Comment: @fikkatra wrote excellent answer with how-to for this.

Comment: as simple as `this.getNumber = function(){ return i++; }` and then use as `cs.getNumber();`

Comment: ah why in the first place I didn't know that! I should execute the function in my service! thanks @vp_arth ! u saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

`CountingService.getNumber` (`getItem`?) is a self-invoking function (IIFE). You assign the result of this function to `CountingService.getNumber`. This happens when the code is first executed. That's why, when you later change localstorage and call `getNumber` again, you won't see any changes. Try this:

```
.factory("CountingService", function() {
    this.getNumber = function() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('cart') != null){
          var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
          var totalItem = 0;
          for(var i=0;i<cart.length;i++){
            totalItem += cart[i].qty;
          }
          return totalItem;
      } else{
        return 0;
      }
    };

    return this;
  })
```

and use it like this:

```
console.log(CountingService.getNumber())
```